# Get specific information from XML input using PLSQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

input XML

```
<major>
    <minor>
        <line_id>12345</line_id>
        <service_Line>
            <line_id>1111</line_id>
            <product_id>56789</product_id>
        </service_Line>
        <service_Line>
            <line_id>22222</line_id>
        </service_Line>
        <service_Line>
            <line_id>3333</line_id>
            <product_id>23456</product_id>
            <product_id>999999</product_id>
        </service_Line>
        <service_Line>
            <line_id>4444</line_id>
        </service_Line>
    </minor>
    <service_Line>
        <line_id>5555</line_id>
        <product_id>666666</product_id>
        <product_id>121212</product_id>
    </service_Line>
    <service_Line>
        <line_id>5555</line_id>
    </service_Line>
</major>
```

from the above XML

I want the line_id and the Product_id of the service_line tag and ignore the line_id in the service_line tag which does not have product_id

so i need the below information

so i need the below information

Out put  -

**Service LIne -- 1111**

```
 Product_id -- 56789
```

**Service Line -- 3333**

```
 Product_id -23456
 Product_id - 999999
```

**Service Line -- 5555**

```
   Product_id -666666
   Product_id - 121212`
```

Oracle Version :
PLSQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

Comment: I need the output like

Comment: so i need the below information
 
Service LIne -- 1111
     Product_id -- 56789
Service Line -- 3333
     Product_id -23456
     Product_id - 999999
Service Line -- 5555
       Product_id -666666
       Product_id - 121212`

Comment: Is "use XPath or an XML parser in your application code" a viable alternative? Because trying to process XML in Oracle... ew. =(

Comment: Hey... Jpmc, i googled it , but unable to get this output.. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might help you:

```
WITH xml_table AS (SELECT XMLTYPE(
'<major>
    <minor>
    <line_id>12345</line_id>
    <service_Line>
        <line_id>1111</line_id>
        <product_id>56789</product_id>
    </service_Line>
    <service_Line>
        <line_id>22222</line_id>
    </service_Line>
    <service_Line>
        <line_id>3333</line_id>
        <product_id>23456</product_id>
        <product_id>999999</product_id>
    </service_Line>
    <service_Line>
        <line_id>4444</line_id>
    </service_Line>
</minor>
<service_Line>
    <line_id>5555</line_id>
    <product_id>666666</product_id>
    <product_id>121212</product_id>
</service_Line>
<service_Line>
    <line_id>5555</line_id>
</service_Line>
</major>') xml FROM DUAL)
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(SERVICE_LINE),'/line_id') line_id,  EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(SERVICE_LINE),'/product_id') product_id
FROM xml_table, TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(xml_table.xml,'//service_Line/*'))) service_line
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo for your query :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the function extractvalue? It must be used in the select clause of a query but you can easily solve that by selecting from dual.

```
select extractvalue(xml, '/major/minor/service_Line/line_id') into v_value from dual;
```

Please note that the input XML must be of the type XMLtype. You can convert a string to XMLtype with the function xmltype(String).

Link to Oracle's documentation for extractvalue: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions054.htm#SQLRF06173

This will not solve your entire problem but I hope it will point you in the right direction.